# Ubuntu 10 Setup - Imaging - Coming for Windows

Tags: ubuntu

On a normal Ubuntu 10.04 desktop installation on x86. Am I correct in thinking, if I move country etc.. I can just take the hard drive out and plug into a new host machine wherever I go, it doesnt matter if first machine was really an AMD/2GB/SATA/Foxconn and next is Dell/Intel/4GB/Supermicro ? With the exception of maybe reconfiguring Nvidia/AMD setup?

Equally once I get my desktop setup with all the tooling (several hours) etc.. rather than redo the same on the laptop I'll just raw copy the image across to a partition on the laptop and install grub / setup mbr.

Linux will redo detection each time at startup unlike win7/vista and wga etc..

Answer (score 1):

You may have to rebuild the initrd on drive transplant and reinstall grub on image copy, but in general Linux does far better when changing iron than any version of Windows since 3.11.